# Animate Relative layout width change

Tags: android, animation

Am trying to do a simple animation in order scale a relative layout's width. I managed to do it using this code but the animation is done very quickly even with 5000ms duration. I cant see the intermidiate results. Any suggestion?

```
RelativeLayout baseLayer;
RelativeLayout fillLayer;
public void animate(int duration){
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
        {
            fillLayer.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(baseLayer.getLayoutParams().width * interpolatedTime);
            fillLayer.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(duration);
    a.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    fillLayer.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was that i was calling the animation method from OnStart(). Now am calling it from onWindowFocusChanged().

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    testBar.animate(2000,0.8);
}

RelativeLayout baseLayer;
RelativeLayout fillLayer;
public void animate(int duration,float fillPercentage){

    final int targetWidth = (int)(baseLayer.getMeasuredWidth() * fillPercentage);        

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
        {
            fillLayer.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(targetWidth * interpolatedTime);
            fillLayer.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(duration);
    a.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    fillLayer.startAnimation(a);
}
```

And throughout this procedure I have found from other post an alternative way to do the same job. But again it the method need to be called form the onWindowFocusChanged().

```
ValueAnimator.ofObject(new WidthEvaluator(fillLayer), fillLayer.getLayoutParams().width, targetWidth).setDuration(2000).start();

class WidthEvaluator extends IntEvaluator {

   private View v;
   public WidthEvaluator(View v) {
     this.v = v;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue) {
      int num = (Integer)super.evaluate(fraction, (Integer)startValue, (Integer)endValue);
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
      params.width = num;
      v.setLayoutParams(params);
      return num;
   }
}
```

[Update Solution]

Following to that I have added my custom views into a ListView and then the problems started again. ListView should be getting ready before views get their actual size. So the animation wasn't able to be done because getMeasuredWidth() was returning always 0 (this was and the problem from the beginning).

So what i did is i used this code snippet in OnCreate().

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = listBars.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {       
            if (!HackClass.GlobalDrawnFlag) {                     
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                HackClass.GlobalDrawnFlag = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

And this inside my list adapter class

```
if (item.getMeasuredWidth==0)
    HackClass.GlobalDrawnFlag = false;
else 
    HackClass.GlobalDrawnFlag = true;
```

This approach solved all my problems apparently. However is that a good solution ? Any other suggestion is welcome.